# Getting template to match different sequences of const T* and non-const T*

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, c++14, constants

This is a template from some refactored code. `drPin` and `drPort` are both subclasses of `drNode`. This code strips the `const` qualification from the original contained pointer, and builds two new data structures based on it (the new data structures need a pointer to non-const in the map because the code that uses them isn't all properly const-restricted). Right now, the first argument is either a `const std::vector<const drPin*>` or a `const std::vector<drPort*>`. To get the second to match, I'm currently copying it over to a vector of `const drPort*` before calling: `std::vector<const drPort*> constPorts(aPorts.cbegin(), aPorts.cend());`

```
template <typename T>
static void buildFlatNetNodes(const std::vector<const T*>& aPins,
                              std::map<drNet*, std::list<drNode*>> &flatNetNodes,
                              std::vector<drNet *> &netOrder)
{
    for (const T* constPin : aPins)
    {
        T *curPin = const_cast<T *>(constPin);
        drNet* curFlatNet = curPin->getNet();
        auto ii = flatNetNodes.find(curFlatNet);
        if (ii == flatNetNodes.end())
        {
            flatNetNodes[curFlatNet] = std::list<drNode *>{curPin};
            netOrder.push_back(curFlatNet);
        }
        else
            ii->second.push_back(curPin);
    }
}
```

Now I'd like to use that same template on a `std::list<drNode*>`.  I could do the same copying trick to get a `std::vector<const drNode*>`, but this list is going to be a lot longer than the vector of ports was, so the extra copying overhead will be correspondingly bigger, and I'd like to avoid it. Trying to make the container type generic (by adding another layer of template and declaring the first type as `const S<const T*>`) failed to compile when invoked with a `std::list<const drNode*>`.  Using begin/end iterators instead of passing the container by reference might work - any other suggestions?  And is there a way to pass a container of `foo*` to code expecting a container of `const foo*`?  (I seem to remember there's a reason that doesn't work, but I don't seem to have the right combination of search terms to find it at the moment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might do:

```
template <typename T>
T* cast_as_non_const(const T* p)
{
    return const_cast<T*>(p);
}

template <typename T>
static void buildFlatNetNodes(const std::vector<T>& aPins,
                              std::map<drNet*, std::list<drNode*>>& flatNetNodes,
                              std::vector<drNet*>& netOrder)
{
    for (const auto* constPin : aPins)
    {
        auto* curPin = cast_as_non_const(constPin);
        drNet* curFlatNet = curPin->getNet();
        auto ii = flatNetNodes.find(curFlatNet);
        if (ii == flatNetNodes.end())
        {
            flatNetNodes[curFlatNet] = {curPin};
            netOrder.push_back(curFlatNet);
        }
        else
            ii->second.push_back(curPin);
    }
}
// std::vector<const drPin*> pins;
// std::vector<drPort*> ports;
// std::map<drNet*, std::list<drNode*>> flatNetNodes;
// std::vector<drNet*> netOrder;
//
// buildFlatNetNodes(pins, flatNetNodes, netOrder);
// buildFlatNetNodes(ports, flatNetNodes, netOrder);
```

Comment: Bingo.  And if I change the declaration of aPins to const T& aPins, it works for the std::list version also.  This is what I needed.  Thanks!